# How to hide C# DataGridView default * row?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

C# DataGridView controls have a default, empty last row, marked with a *. How can I hide it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The row you speak of is the 'new row' row. This can be hidden by setting the AllowUserToAddRows property to false.

Alternatively you can uncheck the 'Enable Adding' tick box in the DataGridView Tasks dialog.
[image: See below:]

Answer (score 6):

Disable [AllowUserToAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx) property. This property indicating whether the option to add rows(that you call default * row) is displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I aggree with Reniuz, if AllowUserToAddRows is enabled, a default row will automatically be generated and added to the row collection.

Comment: If you agree with an existing answer just vote for it, don't add duplicate answers...

Comment: Oh sorry my bad